# Creating a ordering and checkout system, protecting against changing the cart during payment

Tags: php, e-commerce

So I have a multi paged checkout system that relies on sessions to store the contents of the shopping cart. I'm also using a third party system to process credit cards, which hosts the actual payment page on their servers. I just have to POST to the page the final total.

The problem I foresee is what if someone clicks to go to the hosted pay page, and then for some legitimate or nefarious reason changes the shopping cart contents in another tab. I had initially planned that when the hosted pay page redirects back to my receipt page I would then  INSERT the order into my database. But, if the session is changed at that point, the order will be different from the total cost charged.

What would be a solution to this problem. I can see this sort of thing being an issue for all cart systems, so I'm wondering how they do it.

Maybe when the user clicks the button to go to the hosted paypage I can make a temporary order entry in a temp_order table in the database, and then when the payment goes through I can transfer that temp record into the permanent record table? That way I don't insert the record from the session information that has changed. But if I have to POST to the hosted pay page, where do I have the opportunity to save the shopping cart to the temp table?

Also, the temp order id must be unique across both temp and permanent tables since I don't want any overlap.

Lastly, I should want to clear the temp order table frequently as they are just temp records. Some might not go through as the user could change their mind on the hosted pay page.

I'm really confused as to what I should do!

Comment: Moneris. It's a canadian company

Answer (score 2):

I see no need to create a separate table. Just add one column into existing table, say,  `payment_in_progress` and analyse it when client submits any changes to the cart.

The requirement to clear out unprocessed outdated orders remains

Comment: Food for thought. If the user goes to the payment page and is declined, do you need to clear the flag? If the user goes to the payment page and hits the back button, how will you handle that?

Comment: If the payment request will be declined you should get a negative response from the payment processor, so you can clear the flag. As for the back button - I have no idea presently as my suggestion is based on my experience in web programming that I got not in the recent past

Comment: anyway this locked out order should be cleaned up when it gets too old.

Comment: +1. This is what I do with PayPal and it works just fine. I like to name a boolean column 'paid' and mark it true when I get the payment confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

When the payment gateway returns just store the amount received against the shopping cart and if the amount received is less then the total, put them back onto the payment page, showing the outstanding balance left to pay.

Comment: This really adds more problems than you might realize. Many users will feel like they already paid and be unlikely to continue. The cart should be "frozen" as a payment begins so the user cannot get in this situation in the first place.

Comment: @jimp The only reason a user will get into the problem in the first place is if they are trying to cheat the system. If they have paid the full amount then they will wind up on the order confirmation page and know no different. Once the full payment is received, clear the session so they can't edit the cart.

Comment: They would get into that situation if the user edited their cart in another tab, too.

Comment: I thought about this solution before reading the topic and it might be the best one. What to do if it happened? It depends on the company policies. We can report it to the administrators of the system.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the payment system returns control to your website before final processing of the order, e.g. like PayPal Express Checkout, there is no way to stay in control of the checkout process. One-way checkout systems are really meant to be one-way. Follow-up management is manual (by a payment receipt) or handled by server to server notifications.

Posting directly to the payment site is not going to give you any control once you submit away to the other website. Probably the best case scenario is you submit the order to your website as an UNPAID order into your database, then provide a page that says "You're almost finished. Continue to payment." -- At this point, you should have also emptied the customer's cart so they cannot change anything about the order in process (which is already in your DB). When the payment system redirects back to your website, you will simply look for the unpaid order and mark it paid. It would also be a good idea to verify the payment amount, just in case the user modified the POST data in an effort to pay less.

**EDIT:**
You might really be in need of a payment gateway solution that gives you more control over the checkout process. Your concerns are real, but they are not typically addressed adequately using payment flows that send the user directly away from your website without first setting up the transaction server-side.

Comment: Thanks. Now, I don't want to add another step to the process if I don't have to. So is there a way to add the record to the database and post to the hosted pay page on the same click? Well I know there is a redirect and using javascript to manually submit a post, but is there a "safer" way?

Comment: You cannot POST to two different URL's, but you could remove the extra step but recording the cart in your database on the "Verify" step (you have one?) and let the verify page submit directly to the payment.

Comment: Insert when the user loads the verify page, then on clicked "verify" I post to the hosted pay page? Or do you mean insert on clicking "verify" and then use javascript to submit to the pay page? At the point where the user clicks to move to the pay page is when I want to insert and clear the session, since if they are still on the website they might want to go back to make changes.

Comment: I mean show them the verify page, then have a button that says "Continue to Payment" which really submits to the payment gateway. Unfortunately that doesn't give you a chance to clear the session, though, so the page between Verify and the payment gateway might really be necessary. Perhaps your best option would be checking with  Moneris to see if they can accept a GET as well. Then you could submit to yourself, record the payment, and redirect to them.

Comment: I added one paragraph to my answer, that might interest your work. It is possible the gateway you are using doesn't give you the level of control you want.

Comment: Yes, sending the user away is limiting. This particular company does offer an api, but due to budget and time I have to use this method. Thanks for the help. I'll compromise and add the extra step.