# Adding additional cart items during checkout dilemma

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I am having a problem on an e-comm site i am trying to build where it's possible for a user to add additional cart items when checking out with the SecurePay payment gateway.

When the user clicks 'pay now' button, they are redirected off site to the SecurePay payment page where they enter their credit card information. It's here where its possible for the user to open another page and add/remove cart items after the payment information has already been sent to the payment gateway without me being able to detect it. The shopping cart is a database shopping cart with a cookie as a unique identifier to remember the user.

The problem is that there is no input fields to for any product data in the SecurePay form that's sent to the payment gateway, you can only specify limited information about the order, ie, the total $ amount of the order including shipping(can't even send shipping total separately), a reference number(invoice number) and the currency type(AUD), surcharge percentage etc. So i have to process everything based on the the users shopping cart after the order is successful and they are redirect back to my site. If the user add/removes cart items while they are paying offsite, it is then reflected when i generate the invoice and do the stock take on the order completion page.

Im just not sure how to combat this.

My possible scenario:

I lock the cart when the user hits the checkout page, then unlock it if they hit any other page than the checkout page. Though then there is no possibility  of any up selling without taking the user completely out of the checkout process and i'm also worried about any possible scenarios where if the user returns to the site their cart may still be locked. Plus maybe it seems a little messy/hackish of a solution?

I did test a couple random e-comm sites, and it was also possible to add additional cart items from another page during the 'pay now' stage of the checkout process without it detecting the additional cart items unless you actually manually refresh the page. Though i did not verify by actually paying for the items, but i can't see how it would be any different to my problem.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I initially thought this kind of behaviour was a bug until I learned about upselling. So my solution to this (if I ever needed one), is to make sure every checkout process is a new order, and not a update. And add a hook, to let the user know about the new order, and give an option to discard (clear out) items currently in the cart.

Comment: also try reading this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646200/creating-a-ordering-and-checkout-system-protecting-against-changing-the-cart-du?rq=1>

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The solution i came up with was to create a column in the 'orders' table called 'product_array' and save the contents of the shopping cart as a string with delimiters as the user clicks 'pay now'. If the payment is successful then i explode that string into an array and process the order from there rather than the shopping cart. That way if the user does try to manipulate the cart from another tab after they've proceeded to hosted payment page it becomes irrellevant

Answer (score 0):

If you can send a reference number, why not use that to generate the order? Whenever the user goes to pay, create an order with the items in their basket and send that number to SecurePay. When the payment is complete mark that order as paid for. If they change the contents of the basket then the old reference number will still refer to the products originally in the basket and if they go to check out again a new order will be created with the correct items in it.

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand how you mean to have an old reference number? I generate a temporary order with and invoice number when the user starts the checkout process, i send the invoice number as the reference to SecurePay so i can point to the order when the user is redirected back to the site. SecurePay only allows one reference number. Maybe i can update the temporary order and store the basket contents and qty as an array when the user goes to pay, then just loop through the array to get the product items and qty when the order is successful rather than looping through the users basket

Answer (score 0):

There could be an option - that when the user is redirected back to your  site - that secure pay could pass back some information including the amount charged. Then you could check and confirm that figure against whatever is in the cart.

Or - I'm looking at the secure pay developers page and they have two different methods where the customer would never leave your website. 
https://www.securepay.com.au/developers/products-and-services/accepting-e-commerce-payments/

Are you in Australia - if yes you could also look at Stripe, it might be easier https://stripe.com/au/pricing